# How can I Inject JavaScript code into a window object

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, inject

I am trying to make a JavaScript injector for any website so you don't have to rely on bookmarklets and such. Every time I run my code, it tells me that my `newWin.window.location.href = 'about:blank'`, and it tells me that my `newWin.document.body.parentElement.innerHTML = '<head><body></body></head>'`

Note: I am using `alert();` instead of `console.log();` beacuse DevTools is blocked

My Code:

```
let newWin = window.open('https://my_example.com');
try{
    var js_code = newWin.document.createElement('script');
    js_code.setAttribute('source.js',''); //Note that source.js has "alert('Hello World')" in it
    document.head.appendChild(js_code);
    alert(newWin.document.body.parentElement.innerHTML)    

} catch (error){
    alert(error);
}
```

I tried to set the window location manually but it stayed the same:

```
newWin.window.location.href = "https://my_example.com"
```

but to no avail.

I also tried to use:

```
document.write(newWin.document.body.parentElement.innerHTML + '<script>alert("Hello World")</script>
```

Comment: For a start your .settAttribute is missing the attribute name https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Your trying to do web-development at a place where *DevTools is blocked*? Whomever made the decision needs a slap.   Tell them they need to unblock it if they want you to do development.

Comment: I hope this is not possible. Imagine someone could place a legitimate link to your bank's website on their own site and inject javascript on the target site when you click it.

Comment: You can only access the contents of `newWin` if it's in the same domain as the page that opens it. This is a critical security measure in browsers.